# Why does the file created using a text editor contain one byte more than expected?

Tags: c, linux

I created a file like this

> ```
> a v
> bb
> e
> ```

And I **didn't** press `enter` after typing `e` in the last line.

So there are four characters in the first line `'a',' ','v','\n'`.

There are three characters in the second line `'b','b','\n'`.

And there is one character in the last line `'e'`.

So there are totally 8 characters in this file. But when I count the characters using the following C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
int main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

It gave me 9. Even when I use `wc` command to count, it is still 9. Why?

Comment: Something added the extra newline.   You can verify with a command such as `od -c` (or `ls -l`, of course!).  What command did you use to create the file?  Most editors will add the final newline automatically.  You can do it with plain `cat` but you'd have to type control-D twice after the 'e'.

Comment: *"I created a file like this"* -- **how** did you create the file? Some editors automatically put a newline at the end of the last line of the file (if it is not already there).

Comment: What editor are you using? vi/vim adds a newline for you.

Comment: Your editor is properly adding a POSIX *end-of-file*. Some editors provide an option for end of line clean-up, others are just oblivious to the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's reasoning in favor of having all lines terminated with a newline character:

- [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/1025391)

And there are text editors that are set up to add a trailing newline character automatically (if not already there):

- [How to stop Gedit, Gvim, Vim, Nano from adding End-of-File newline char?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13317)

Probably that is why you observe the unexpected file size.

To inspect the actual content of such files, I like to use `hexdump`:

```
$ hexdump -C test
00000000  61 20 76 0a 62 62 0a 65  0a                       |a v.bb.e.|
00000009
```